# How do I go back to previous fragment programatically with navigation component in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I need to go back to previous fragment programatically with navigation component in kotlin. How do I set on click listener on button with this functionality?

Comment: You should probably take the time to read the documentation before asking here: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#back-stack

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just call popBackStack() method on your NavController, on click of that button
Something like:

```
findNavController().popBackStack()
```

For more [check Navigation Component docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#back-stack)

Answer (score 4):

As per the [Navigation and the back stack guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#back-stack), you'd want to use NavController's [`popBackStack()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#popBackStack()) to pop the back stack and go back to the previous fragment.